# How do I embed a CodePen in my web page?

Tags: html, css, embed

I tried adding a CodePen (from codepen.io) to my web page, but it does not show up the way I want it to. It only shows the text: 'See the Pen ... on CodePen'. [The picture I added shows the embed window on CodePen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uB71.png)

How I can properly embed the Pen, so it completely shows up on my webpage? Sorry if this is a really dumb question, I am still a complete noob in HTML.

Comment: I never had done it but it seems that there is a good [tutorial](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/)

Comment: Yes I did that but it does not work. Can someone show me a code example of the embedded Pen in an html document?

Comment: Maybe add a code example on what you want to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use this locally, replace

`<script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>`

With

`<script async src="http://assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>`

**Why?**

As you can see, the default script's `src` starts with `//assets...`.

They removed the protocol in the URL so that it automatically matches your own. This is common practice, because `https` sites don't allow scripts to be loaded with `http` URLs.

So, if your site uses `http`, the script will be loaded with `http`. If your site uses `https`, it will be loaded with `https`.

But if your site is not on a server, and is opened with the `file:///` protocol, it just won't find that resource on your machine, so you need to specify the protocol to use.

Answer (score 3):

I'm wondering if perhaps your page is not online yet. I recently embedded codepen into my own webpage and I noticed that I couldn't see it on my computer locally but when I uploaded my html to my server, it was there.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, will you click the up arrow to the left and the check mark below it please?

Answer (score 3):

[Embedded Pens](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/)

You can embed Pens on other websites with our copy-and-paste Embed code. To get the code, click the "Embed" button in the footer of the Editor on any Pen. Or, select "Embed Pen" from the export menu.

[image]

This will open the Embed Builder.

[image]

The Embed Builder helps you customize your embed. You can:

**Choose your embed theme:** We have two built-in themes: Light and Dark. Every CodePen also gets a customizable, personal default theme. PRO members get unlimited embed themes.

**Choose which tabs to display:** the embed builder will start out with your result tab and one of your code tabs selected. You can choose a different code tab, turn off the code tabs entirely to maximize the result, or hide the result and maximize a code tab.

**Make the preview "Click-to-Load":** Check the checkbox next to "use click-to-load" to enable the preview version for your embedded Pen. Preview embeds show a static image preview of your Pen with a "Run Pen" button. When your visitors click the button, the Pen will load.

**Make the embed editable:** PRO members can make their embeds editable, just like the editor on CodePen. You can read more about how editable embeds work in our PRO Embeds documentation.

**Set the embed height:** Drag the bar at the bottom of the embed to change its height. The Copy & Paste code will update with the new height.

After you've finished customizing the embed code, copy the code from the "Copy & Paste Code" box below the embed preview. Paste the code into your website and your embed will appear.

Here's an example of what the embed code looks like. It is HTML:

```
<p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="ClnAe" data-user="afkatja" data-default-tab="result" class='codepen'>See the Pen <a href='http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/ClnAe'>ClnAe</a> by Katja Hollar (<a href='http://codepen.io/afkatja'>@afkatja</a>) on <a href='http://codepen.io'>CodePen</a></p>
```

[Read on..](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/)

Comment: Hi, what about privacy? Is there a cookie / external source hint needed? Or can that embed be "behind" a "Click: Yes, I agree ..."

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the problem, you just have to copy the code that gives you Codepen:

```html
 <p>Codepen embed:</p>
    <p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="vGNKNj" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="blonfu" data-embed-version="2" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/vGNKNj/">Modificar color de texto según fondo (stylus)</a> by blonfu (<a href="http://codepen.io/blonfu">@blonfu</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
    <script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```